# Difference between let and run kotlin scoped function

Tags: android, kotlin

If we can use `let` to avoid a null pointer exception, why do we need the `run` function?

Some articles say `run` in combination of `with` and `let`, but if alone `let` is sufficient, then what is the point of the introduction of the `run` function?

Answer (score 2):

The primary difference when you try to use `let` and `run` is how they expose their targets.

`let` exposes the object with the `it` keyword while `run` reveals it with the `this` keyword, which makes the object properties and methods available in context and you don't need to write `this` to reference them anymore. as oppose to `let` where you have to repeat `it` each time you want to call a property or a method of the target object.

Please check this [documentation link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#function-selection) to see the differences and cases where you can't use `let` but should use `run` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you can use `let` to avoid null pointer exceptions, but `let` on its own is insufficient. What helps you to avoid NPE is the `?.` operator ([documented here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls)). This helps to make your code more concise: instead of

```
if (foo != null)
    foo.bar()
```

you can do

```
foo?.bar()
```

(To be precise, the direct translation of the `?.` operator would be `if (foo == null) null else foo.bar()` but quite often we're discarding the null case.)

Now, combining this with the `let` function, you can make complex-looking code more concise (and possibly more readable). Instead of:

```
val foo = getMeSomeFoo()
if (foo != null) {
    doSomething(foo)
    return foo.bar()
} else {
    return null
}
```

you can do

```
return getMeSomeFoo()?.let { foo ->
    doSomething(foo)
    foo.bar()
}
```

The code inside the `{...}` is called the *block* parameter to the `let` function, and the block is another function (or a lambda) which takes `let`'s receiver (in this case, `getMeSomeFoo()` if it's not null) as a parameter, and we've named this parameter `foo` in the lambda. For short blocks, you can omit `foo ->` and just use the default name, `it`.

The `let` function is one of several so-called [scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html). You can also use `run` in the same way but instead of `it`, you would have to use `this`. However, `let` is more usual and idiomatic in this usage.

I've made this table of scope functions which I find to be a useful reference:

|  | Return x | Return y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **this** | x.apply { y } | x.run { y } with(x) { y } |
| **it** | x.also { y } | x.let { y } |
| — |  | run { y } |

Comment: `return foo.bar()` should be just `foo.bar()` or `return@let foo.bar()` in your last code block.