# Use of scope functions in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, scope

I am going through with scope functions in kotlin. I found many articles and examples for using these functions. But haven't got anything that can explain on which scenarios which function to use. Also what is **difference between it and this keyword**, Can anyone please explain the difference? Here's a simple example of use of scope functions which is doing similar task. **If similar task can be done with different functions, then why use different scope functions?**

```
fun main() {
    val person = Person()
    person.let {
        it.name = "let HelloWorld"
        println(it.name)
        println("let $it")
    }
    println("let.. $person")
    with(person) {
        name = "With HelloWorld"
        println(this.name)
        println(this)
    }
    println(person)
    person.run {
        name = "Run HelloWorld"
        println(this.name)
        println(this)
    }
    println(person)
    person.apply {
        name = "apply HelloWorld"
        println(this.name)
        println(this)
    }
    println(person)
    person.also {
        it.name = "Also HelloWorld"
        println(it.name)
        println(it)
    }
    println(person)
}

data class Person(var name:String="", var age:Int = 0)
```

Comment: If you say you already read examples of usages, then to be honest, I'm not exactly sure what other answer you expect. Scope functions are just tiny utils that could help make our code cleaner... or dirtier, if used irresponsibly. We choose one or another depending on which one fits better into our specific case. Of course, if for example we don't use a return value, then there is no difference between `let` and `also`. Then we can choose purely by its name, so the code reads better as a sentence in English.

Comment: Related (but not identical) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77227603/difference-between-let-and-run-kotlin-scoped-function

Answer (score 3):

It is already explained in the Kotlin [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html).

> Basically, these functions all perform the same action: execute a
> block of code on an object. What's different is how this object
> becomes available inside the block and what the result of the whole
> expression is.

Due to the many similarities between scope functions, choosing the right one for your use case can be tricky

It will help you to achieve all the [differences](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#function-selection).

Short Guide

- Executing a lambda on non-nullable objects: `let`
- Introducing an expression as a variable in local scope: `let`
- Object configuration: `apply`
- Object configuration and computing the result: `run`
- Running statements where an expression is required: non-extension `run`
- Additional effects: `also`
- Grouping function calls on an object: `with`